# Why is it the $ x^2 + y^2 -\cos(z) <5 $ is unbounded, but $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 -\cos(z) <5 $ isn't?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am having a real hard time with this question. I know something is bounded if $\exists  r>0$ s.t. $S\subset\beta(r,0)$

So with a function like $x^2 + y^2 - \cos(z) <5$. Why is it unbounded? Compared to  $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - \cos(z) <5$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Since $-1\le\cos z\le 1$, if you have $x^2+y^2+z^2-\cos z<5$, then also
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2<6
$$
and so the set $\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2-\cos z<5\}$ is contained in the sphere centered at the origin with radius $\sqrt{6}$.

Conversely, take $x=0$ and $y=0$; then for *any* $z$ you have
$$
x^2+y^2-\cos z<5
$$
which obviously makes the set $\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2-\cos z<5\}$ unbounded.

Comment: Thank you. So from my understanding with the unbounded function, there is a certain limit for what the variables can be to achieve the inequality, but with the unbounded version, a certain variable can be any number which is impossible to bound right?

Comment: @GeorgeHarrison The situation could be more complicated, but in this case $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2<6\}$ is certainly bounded, it's the variable $z$ that one should check.

Comment: So its bounded because if we make x and y = to 0, then z can be anything and that won't satisfy it. But with $x^2 + y^2 +z^2 - cos(z), if x and y are 0, there is a bound to what z can be right?

Comment: @GeorgeHarrison Not sure to understand.